# Nginx rewrite urls to match proxy address

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, proxy

I am running a wordpress docker container , the site is accessible through host machines port `8000` , if go to localhost:8000 boom i get to see my wordpress site.

It's boring to always type `localhost:8000` to see my website, so i decided to commission nginx as a reverse proxy for my site. I've set up a virtual host in nginx that has the name `proxy.site` , i can now access by wordpress site by visiting `http://proxy.site`.

Up until this point, we are doing great, when `http://proxy.site` opens up, i can see a list of my blog posts, lets say i want to read my latest blog post about COVID-19 , when i click on the link, ohohohoho it opens up as `http://localhost:8000/posts/covid19`

I want it to open with the proxy url as in `http://proxy.site/posts/covid19` , i need to whole site to be accessible through the `http://proxy.site` site name,

I need nginx to rewrite all my links in `localhost:8000/*` to `proxy.site/*` , no body loves typing ports when accessing a blog,

Here is how my nginx conf file looks like

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/proxy.site/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name proxy.site www.proxy.site;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                #proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                #proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/ http://proxy.site/ ;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

How do i achieve rewrite all urls in the proxied site with my custom host name ?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not listen to localhost:8080, nginx will not inspect links from your site to rewrite them, you should find a way on WordPress to replace base url of your links.based on the environment

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. What you are saying won't work since changing the site url in wordpress will make the wordpress site inaccessible from the outside world, i've tried that but it simply didn't work

Comment: What I mean is ,find a way in WordPress to update or rewrite links to match your virtual host address, this has nothing to do with nginx.